# How does an attacker compromise a soft switch?

Tags: encryption, network, penetration-test, attacks, network-scanners

Speaking of soft switches (e.g soft switch in data plane of [software defined networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_networking)). I've been trying to find a good research paper or article that explains how an attacker can compromise a soft switch to tamper flow routing table or perform any other kind of attacks. I think this can be done by compromising a host connected to that soft switch. If this is the case, I still don't know how to be able to tamper the soft switch.

In fact, I want to understand these things conceptually for the sake of my research.

Comment: Because of its high level design, it is usually easier to secure an SDN network.  Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_networking#Security_using_the_SDN_paradigm for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Testing SDN including soft switches can be accomplished with the [delta](https://github.com/OpenNetworkingFoundation/delta) GitHub project from -- http://opensourcesdn.org/projects/project-delta-sdn-security-evaluation-framework/

Ivan Pepelnjak, at his [blog](http://blog.ipspace.net/search/label/security), but also in his [2014 Troopers conference talk](https://www.troopers.de/events/troopers14/33_security_and_sdn__a_perfect_fit_or_oil-and-water/) (YouTube video [here](https://youtu.be/s2FIen4lI_w)), discusses security issues with Software Defined Networks regularly.

Comment: https://github.com/smythtech/sdnpwn